# How do I create an efficient long, pannable, sprite-animated scene in a Windows Store game?

Tags: directx, spritesheet, windows-8

I am creating my first Windows Store application in XAML, and I cannot seem to find a proper example for the requirements I have.

The basic idea of the app is to have a large scrollable canvas which would lazily start animating visible parts of the view as soon as user stops panning over a certain content (with some audio played also):

[image: As the user pans to the right, new content is revealed and animations start when panning stops for a moment]

My original idea was to use a `StackPanel` to add a bunch of custom controls, each of which would then animate itself once visible (with a short delay), but I have a couple of concerns:

1. If the entire canvas is ~50 screen widths wide, is it feasible to load all content at the beginning, or do I need to plan doing some lazy loading during scrolling? For example, when I select a certain region in the Bing Travel app, it seems to lazily load tiles as I scroll it towards the end.
2. Since content is stretched 100% vertically, and these animations are vectorized to be resolution independent, I am not sure if XAML ([`CompositionTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) will be able to handle this, or I have to go for DirectX (MonoGame or C++) to get rid of flicker.
3. Even better, is there an example for Windows 8 which uses a 100% vertically sized `GridView` with custom animated controls inside?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render game content in Windows Store App the best way to do this is SwapChainBackgroundPanel (Windows 8), SwapChainPanel (Windows 8.1)

I think [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Fall-Fury-the-PDF) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Although, it seems like in Windows 8.1 the `SwapChainBackgroundPanel` has become pretty much obsolete with the introduction of the `SwapChainPanel` class.

Comment: Agreed. Updated answer so it's less confusing.